# Java: Inheritance of method

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I have two classes:

```
abstract class A 
{
    private int a;
    protected int get(){return a;}
}

class B extends A
{
    private int a = 2;
}
```

What i want is to inherit get() method which would give me the result 2 instead of 0. I know why this code is not working but have no idea is it even possible to make this kind of trick in java.

Comment: Curious, why would you want to do this?  Is it just a learning exercise?  IRL, name "collisions" like this are often something to consider avoiding, but only because anyone reading the code later might get confused.

Comment: i Have abstract class Effect which is the base of DmgEffect, StunEffect etc. with several variables like duration, value etc. I thought I could write so much less code if it would be possible.

Comment: I suspect that you're overlooking something if you believe that to be the case.  Member variables are never polymorphic in nature.  If you attempt to exploit the fact that a subclass can actually *hide* the access to an otherwise accessible field, then you'll eventually end up in trouble....the exhausted engineer at 3am hopped up on caffeine might well not catch what you're doing.  In your example, you have two private variables, so they're externally hidden already, but you *still* run the risk of confusion.  It's just not something that seasoned OO engineers are accustomed to dealing with.

Comment: See @magnamag's answer for a far more acceptable solution, AND one that engineers would expect to encounter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to override your `get()` method, you could pass the value to your `a` attribute in the constructor:

```
abstract class A {
    private int a;

    protected A(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    protected int get() {
        return this.a;
    }
}

class B
    extends A {

    B() {
        super(2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.get()); // 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for my knowing - Since we did not  instantiated any object of A can we set a value using constructor to A? Here you assign 2 using super(2) to a.

Comment: @Razib `A` is `abstract`, so you cannot instantiate any instance of `A`, but only of its non-abstract subclasses. Regarding your question: yes, you can pass any arguments in the constructor and assign them to the attributes, as long as there exists a constructor that actually accepts those arguments (that's why I created a `protected` constructor in `A` that accepts an `int`).

Comment: @hejcz I'm glad my answer was of help to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can override `get()` in class `B` :

```
class B extends A
{
    private int a = 2;

    @Override
    protected int get() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

This way, calling `get()` on an instance of class `B` would return the `a` member of `B`.

Comment: Well, I know. I was wondering is there a way to just produce less code as I have a variable in both classes. ( so I'm looking for the way of resolving it without actually making get() method in class B - I just want to inherit fully functionally get() from A class).

Comment: you can use super keyword

Comment: @hejcz A's get() would always return A's `a` member, since you can't override a member. If you want to return B's `a` member, you must override get().

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to reiterate that this falls in the category of "crummy technique".  See @Magnamag's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you an accessor such as `getA()` you can use `get()` with all of it's functionality as long as any code inside the definition of `get()` uses `getA()` to get the value of a instead of just using `a`.

Small example:

```
abstract class A 
{
    private int a;

    protected int get(){
        // do anything with getA(), here just return the value as in your question.
        return getA();
    }

    public int getA(){ return a; }
}

class B extends A
{
    private int a = 2;

    @Override
    public int getA(){ return a; }
}
```